# Nested ModelSerializer

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to provide a nested json file through Django Rest Framework. I have been reading up on different way to nest my serializers but I am not getting it to work.

I don't know how to create a modelserializer by myself, instead of directly pulling the data from my model...

My error:

> AttributeError at /listings.json Got AttributeError when attempting to
>   get a value for field `coordinates` on serializer `TestSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any
>   attribute or key on the `Test` instance. Original exception text was:
>   'Test' object has no attribute 'coordinates'.

My serializer code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rentlistings.models import Test


class coordinatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('latitude', 'longitude')


class propertiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('price', 'price', 'yields',
                  'num_floor', 'num_rooms', 'elevator', 'garage',
                  'balcony_size', 'garden_area', 'parking', 'terass',
                  'loggia', 'cellar', 'hash_id')


class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
coordinates = coordinatesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
properties = propertiesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('coordinates', 'properties')
```

My views.py

```
from rentlistings.models import Test
from rentlistings.serializers import TestSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
# Create your views here.


class test_list(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        serializer_class = TestSerializer´
```

After correcting with @aircraft comments, I don't get an error but nothing is included in the API json:

[image]

models.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Test(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    hash_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    price = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    floor = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    garden_area = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    parking = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    terass = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    loggia = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cellar = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    elevator = models.NullBooleanField()
    garage = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    balcony_size = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_floor = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_rooms = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    yields = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TestSerializer`, you should add params like bellow:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    coordinates = coordinatesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    properties = propertiesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('coordinates', 'properties')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! This actually removed the error, but somehow it doesn't include any information (just an empty json with the number of objects I would expect but nothing inside them)....any thoughts? Could it have something to do with me using ModelSerializer for the other two while I use Serializer for the consoldated nested end serializer? Appreciate your help!

Comment: show the models. maybe there is no related_name in the foreigh key.

Comment: @Svarto there is big wrong. there is no foreigh model there! if you want to use nest serializer. it shoul base on foregh key.

Comment: Oh, ok, I'm confused. I just want to structure my json File so that it has the coordinates under one node and the properties under another - similar to a GeoJSON. I'll read up on foreignkeys, thanks for the tip!